# How to find the integer values of this function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Are there any $y=x+x^2$ where $x>1, x \in \mathbf{Q}, x \notin \mathbf{N}, y \in \mathbf{N}$?

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Find $x$ using the quadratic formula, then vary $y$. What can you deduce?

Comment: $x\in\mathbb{Q}$, then exist $m\in\mathbb{Z}, n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x=\frac{m}{n}$. $x>1$, then $m>n$. Let $k=gcd(m,n)$, $m_1=m/k$, $n_1=n/k$, then $x=\frac{m_1}{n_1}$, $m_1>n_1$, $gcd(m_1,n_1)=1$. $x\notin \mathbb{Q}$, then $n_1>1$. $x+x^2=\frac{m_1 n_1+m_1^2}{n_1^2}$. Let $gcd(m_1n_1+m_1^2,n_1^2)=l$. If $l\neq 1$, then exists prime factor of $l$ which must divide both $m_1n_1+m_1^2$ and $n_1^2$, but then this prime factor must divide both $m_1$ and $n_1$ which contradicts to $gcd(m_1,n_1)=1$. Then $l=1$. Then $\frac{m_1 n_1+m_1^2}{n_1^2}$ is not reducible and not integer ($n_1>1$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $y=n>0$ is some integer solution satisfying

$$n=x+x^2\Rightarrow x=\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4n}}{2}$$

$$x\notin \mathbb{N^+}, \Rightarrow 1+4n=(2k)^2$$

Now we get contradictions, since LHS is odd but RHS is even.
Therefore, no solutions.

Comment: note $x>1$ @Cathedral